# Почему не работает lenght для массива в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой массив в JS:

```
var files = [];
```

В нем один элемент:

```
[1430904228000: "b3ce520734e536cb9a6ecf8665a6f479"]
```

Если сделать так:

```
console.log(files); // Выводит элемент с ключом 1430904228000
   if(files.length > 0){ alert('OK'); // Не выводит сообщение
}
```

Полный код:

```
var files:

set: function (key, hash) {
     files[key] = hash[0];
},

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем

```
function countProperties(obj) {
   var count = 0;

   for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        ++count;
   }

   return count;
}

if(countProperties(files) > 0){ alert('OK');
```

А это как домашнее задание

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Весь код таков: обновил вопрос

Comment: Вы опять показываете какой-то огрызок

Но у меня есть подозрение что в files находится словарь а не массив. И вам надо посчитать количество ключей

Канонический вариант

    function countProperties(obj) {
        var count = 0;

         for(var prop in obj) {
              if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
               ++count;
        }

        return count;
    }

Современный вариант:

      Object.keys({"1":"2"}).length

Comment: Это не синтаксическая конструкция js, это вывод console.log просто.

Comment: Не смотря на то что решение может работать, ответ @MakarovAV более корректен и объясняет причину странного поведения.

Answer (score 3):

Я понял, Вы посмотрели что содержится в массиве через console.log. Console.log автоматически привел строковый индекс к числу, то есть показывает не то, что на самом деле.

1430904228000 это больше чем (2<sup>32</sup>- 2) = 4,294,967,294 - максимальный числовой индекс массива в javascript. Это магическое число существует потому что максимальная  длина массива определена в спеке как максимальное 32хбитное беззнаковое целое, а индексы начинаются с 0.

Массивы в js унаследованы от объектов, и соответственно массиву можно как и любому объекту задать какой-то строковый ключ и его значение, однако изменение строковых ключей массива не затрагивает его свойство `length`, в чем можно легко убедиться в консоли:

```
var arr=[0];
arr["1"]=1; //Строковые индексы которые можно привести к числу, к числу приведутся
arr.smth = 'trololo';
arr["1430904228000"] = 'b3ce520734e536cb9a6ecf8665a6f479';
console.log(arr.smth);
console.log(arr.length);  
console.log(arr); // И здесь мы увидим тот самый "странный" элемент массива который на самом деле строковый.
```

Похоже эта конструкция воспринимается интерпретатором как строковый ключ объекта "1430904228000", поэтому length и не меняется.

Стоит добавить что добавление строковых ключей в массив это плохая практика, так как во-первых рушит оптимизации интерпретатора, во-вторых другие программисты их там обычно не ожидают.

Comment: Очень дельный ответ! Скажите, как тогда добавить элемент в массив, указав строковый ключ? Так: `file.{key} = value`?

Comment: @Jony, не надо добавлять в массив строковые ключи! Это рушит оптимизации интерпретатора и ваще плохая практика

Comment: Как быть тогда? Заменить на объект?

Comment: @Jony, либо заменить на объект либо позаботиться о назначении нормальных числовых ключей которые будут влазить в диапазон числовых значений нормально воспринимаемых массивами

Answer (score 1):

В массиве элементы разделяются `,` , к примеру:

```
[1, 'str', obj]
```

То что представили вы, больше похоже на объект, пример объекта:

```
var obj = {prop : value}
```

Comment: Но ведь добавление происходит как в массив: `files[key] = hash[0];`

Comment: @Jony, к объекту так тоже можно добавить, попробуй